# Azure Python how to link child/related tickets to an already created ticket?

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am using the Azure Python tool to create Epic/Story/Feature work items in a python script like so:

```
# add fields
jpo = JsonPatchOperation()
jpo.from_ = None
jpo.op = "add"
jpo.path = "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.FinishDate"
jpo.value = default_field
jpos.append(jpo)

#create work item
createdWorkItem = wit_client.create_work_item(
    document=jpos,
    project=project.id,
    type="EPIC",
    validate_only=validate_only,
    bypass_rules=bypass_rules,
    suppress_notifications=suppress_notifications
)

#save details to local json file
epic_details = {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/relations/-",
    "value": {
        "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse",
        "name": "Parent",
        "url": createdWorkItem.url
    }
}
```

I need to link my tickets together, such as adding a Child / Parent relationship between tickets. I'm trying to do this by creating all my tickets first, then linking them all where needed.

Is there some way with the Azure Devops Python tool that I can add a child workitem to a epic workitem if both tickets already exist? Thanks.

edit: I've found the function `ParentChildWIMap` referenced here:
https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api/blob/451cade4c475482792cbe9e522c1fee32393139e/azure-devops/azure/devops/v5_1/work/models.py#L711
But I'm unsure on how to use it

Answer (score 0):

If you use https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api , you can try this sample:

```
from azure.devops.connection import Connection
from msrest.authentication import BasicAuthentication
from azure.devops.v6_0.py_pi_api import JsonPatchOperation
import pprint

# Fill in with your personal access token and org URL
personal_access_token = '<pat>'
organization_url = 'https://dev.azure.com/<org>'

# Create a connection to the org
credentials = BasicAuthentication('', personal_access_token)
connection = Connection(base_url=organization_url, creds=credentials)

# Get a client (the "core" client provides access to projects, teams, etc)
wi_client = connection.clients.get_work_item_tracking_client()

parent_id = 2129
child_id = 2217

parent_work_item = wi_client.get_work_item(parent_id);

pprint.pprint(parent_work_item.url)

patch_document = []
patch_document.append(JsonPatchOperation(op='add',path="/relations/-",value={"rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse","url": parent_work_item.url}))


wi_client.update_work_item(patch_document, child_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Took me quite some time to figure this one out too.
Similar to the previous answer, an example on how to create work items with optional subtasks based on content from yaml files:

https://github.com/filipjonckers/azure-devops-bulk-workitems

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33645092)