# azure-devops python error running 'create_work_item'

Tags: python, azure, rest, http, azure-devops

I am trying to use the azure-devops python pip package in order to migrate a large amount of Epic/Story/Feature tickets into Azure Devops. I can create singular tickets just fine, but I'm having trouble linking those tickets together by specifying the hierarchy (ticket A is a parent to child tickets B / C / D)

In order to create an EPIC ticket I'm running code like this:

```
    #set field
    jpo = JsonPatchOperation()
    jpo.from_ = None
    jpo.op = "add"
    jpo.path = "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.FinishDate"
    jpo.value = default_field
    jpos.append(jpo)
    
    #create work item
    createdWorkItem = wit_client.create_work_item(
        document=jpos,
        project=project.id,
        type="EPIC",
        validate_only=validate_only,
        bypass_rules=bypass_rules,
        suppress_notifications=suppress_notifications
    )
```

Which works, but now I'm trying to figure out how to give this Epic ticket a linked Child ticket.

In the github repo for this azure-devops python package, I can see that in the definition for `create_work_item` there is a string variable `expand` which has an option for `Relations`

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api/blob/master/azure-devops/azure/devops/v5_1/work_item_tracking/work_item_tracking_client.py#L1578

```
:param str expand: The expand parameters for work item attributes. Possible options are { None, Relations, Fields, Links, All }.
```

It's also discussed in the official azure-devops documentation for the create_work_item function:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#workitemexpand

But if I add `expand='Relations'` to my code it results in an error:

```
    createdWorkItem = wit_client.create_work_item(
        document=jpos,
        project=project.id,
        type="EPIC",
        validate_only=validate_only,
        bypass_rules=bypass_rules,
        suppress_notifications=suppress_notifications,
        expand='Relations'
    )
```

`TypeError: WorkItemTrackingClient.create_work_item() got an unexpected keyword argument 'expand'`

Am I using this 'expand' variable correctly? Or is there a different way I should add a child ticket to an epic in azure using python? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [User Shamrai Aleksander - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8235971/shamrai-aleksander) . Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

To resolve this  `TypeError: WorkItemTrackingClient.create_work_item() got an unexpected keyword argument 'expand'` error:

Instead of using `expand`, you can append the relation in `patch_document`. You can try this sample:

```
from azure.devops.connection import Connection
from msrest.authentication import BasicAuthentication
from azure.devops.v6_0.py_pi_api import JsonPatchOperation
import pprint

#Fill in with your personal access token and org URL
personal_access_token = '<pat>'
organization_url = 'https://dev.azure.com/<org>'

#Create a connection to the org
credentials = BasicAuthentication('', personal_access_token)
connection = Connection(base_url=organization_url, creds=credentials)

#Get a client (the "core" client provides access to projects, teams, etc)
wi_client = connection.clients.get_work_item_tracking_client()
parent_id = 2129
child_id = 2217
parent_work_item = wi_client.get_work_item(parent_id);
pprint.pprint(parent_work_item.url)
patch_document = []
patch_document.append(JsonPatchOperation(op='add',path="/relations/-",value={"rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse","url": parent_work_item.url}))
wi_client.update_work_item(patch_document, child_id)
```

References: [Azure Python how to link child/related tickets to an already created ticket? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71327037/azure-python-how-to-link-child-related-tickets-to-an-already-created-ticket) and [GitHub - microsoft/azure-devops-python-api: Azure DevOps Python API](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api)