# Azure web api how to view hierarchy related/linked ticket

Tags: azure, http, azure-devops

I have an azure epic ticket (1165) that has a linked child story ticket (1162)
[image]

I want to be able to view this linked child ticket field in the json api view, If I visit the api url for my ticket like so:

[https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/dc37----8a2/_apis/wit/workItems/1165](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/dc37----8a2/_apis/wit/workItems/1165)

I can see most of the fields, except for the linked child task which is missing. you can see in my image I ctrl+f searched for my ticket's description which shows up.

[image]

Is there some way I can format my url so that I can see my tickets linked child items? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `&$expand={$expand}` to the end of your URL:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/dc37----8a2/_apis/wit/workItems/1165?$expand=relations
```

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/get-work-item?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1#workitemexpand

Then check `relations` section:

[image]

Comment: Thank you that does work! Next I need to figure out how to add child/parent links to a ticket programmatically. Either with the azure-devops python package or with HTTP requests. if you have any advice I have that reported in a different ticket: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71327037/azure-python-how-to-link-child-related-tickets-to-an-already-created-ticket